# Partitioning aggregates with groups

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, partitioning

I'm trying to partition an aggregate similar to [the example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions) in the ElasticSearch documentation, but am not getting the example to work.

The index is populated with event-types:

```
public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string SegmentId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

The `EventId` is unique, and each event belongs to a specific `SegmentId`. Each SegmentId can be associated with zero to many events.

**The question is:**
How do I get the latest `EventId` for each `SegmentId`?

I expect the number of unique segments to be in the range of 10 millions, and the number of unique events one or two magnitudes greater. That's why I don't think using `top_hits` by itself is appropriate, as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665142/query-the-latest-document-of-each-type-on-elasticsearch). Hence, partitioning.

**Example:**

I have set up a demo-index populated with 1313 documents (unique `EventId`), belonging to 101 distinct `SegmentId` (i.e. 13 events per segment). I would expect the query below to work, but the exact same results are returned regardless of which `partition` number I specify.

```
POST /demo/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "segments": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "segmentId",
        "size": 15,                  <-- I want 15 segments from each query
        "include": {
          "partition": 0,            <-- Trying to retrieve the first partition
          "num_partitions": 7        <-- Expecting 7 partitions (7*15 > 101 segments)
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": [
              "timestamp",
              "eventId",
              "segmentId"
            ],
            "sort": {
              "timestamp": "desc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I remove the `include` and set `size` to a value greater than 101, I get the latest event for every segment. However, I doubt that is a good approach with a million buckets...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I was investigating the wrong question... My example actually works perfectly.

The problem was my local ElasticSearch node. I don't know what went wrong with it, but when repeating the example on another machine, it worked. I was, however, unable to get partitioning working on my current ES installation. I therefore uninstalled and reinstalled ElasticSearch again, and then the example worked.

**To answer my original question**, the example I provided is the way to go. I solved my problem by using the [cardinality aggregate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) to get an estimate on the total number of products, from which I derived a suitable number of partitions. Then I looped the query above for each partition, and added the documents to a final list.

Comment: Hi Reyhn, I am trying to do the same without sorting, and it seems that on small data sets (tests) i get missing aggregations. I am using version 6.5. Is this api of include exclude using partition is deterministic ?

Comment: I just discovered this pagination option on aggregations recently. But have been wondering how will it perform. I plan to use both as 'nested' 'terms' aggregations instead of top_hits on millions of documents.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do a [Scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) of the aggregation.

Scroll API is supported only for search queries and not for aggregations. If you do not want to use the Top Hits, as you have stated, due to a huge number of documents, you can either try:

1. [Parent/Child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html) approach - where you create segments as a parent document and the events in the child document. And everytime you add a child, you can update the timestamp field in the parent document. By doing so, you can just query the parent documents and you will have your segment id + the last event timestamp
2. Another approach would be you try to get the top hits only for the last 24 hours. So you can add a query to first filter the last 24 hours and then try to get the aggs using the top_hit.

Comment: You are correct in that what I wanted was a scroll on an aggregation, which is not supported. However, I solved it with partitioning (see my accepted answer). Thank you for your suggestions, though! They might come in handy in another situation! (: